# How to remove Post in url link for Blogengine

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, blogengine.net

How to remove Post in url link for Blogengine
http://localhost/blog/post/welcome.aspx

I need to remove **post** from above mentioned url.

" class="taggedlink"><%=Server.HtmlEncode(Post.Title) %>

I need like this format :http://localhost/blog/welcome.aspx
Please solve this.

Comment: Please post your code here, so that we can check and suggest you.

Comment: Hi, <h2 class="post-title">
        <a href="<%=Post.RelativeOrAbsoluteLink %>" class="taggedlink"><%=Server.HtmlEncode(Post.Title) %></a>
    </h2>

Comment: Is this within any grid or repeater?

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

```
<%=Post.RelativeOrAbsoluteLink.Replace("/post/","/") %>
```

Comment: Above mentioned am used but getting the following errors : The resource cannot be found.http://localhost/blog//welcome.aspx

Comment: Why there are two slashes? We just replaced with `/post/` to `/`. So there should be only 1 slash. Show me what you did.

Comment: So I think this is the same format as you want and written in your question.

Comment: Hi, Am getting the following links : localhost/blog/post/welcome.aspx  now its changed to localhost/blog/welcome.aspx , but an Error likes The resource cannot be found

Comment: So it means you have converted to correct link as you want, But there is no welcome.aspx found within blog folder.

Comment: I post called welcome.aspx but it links like this  localhost/blog/post/welcome.aspx

Comment: If welcome.aspx can be accessible via `localhost/blog/post/welcome.aspx`, that cannot be accessible when you remove `post`. If you want to access it, you need to use url rewriting. But I don't understand purpose of it. If you can access it `localhost/blog/post/welcome.aspx`, why do you want to remove post? One more thing you can try, try to move welcome.aspx at blog folder level

Comment: How to extend Number of characters post,

Comment: Settings - > Basic -> Number of characters , I used 100, but does not take this Number of characters please explain where to change

Comment: You mean, post max length? As far as I know, there is no post max length.

Comment: still am not getting proper answers

Comment: Did you able to resolve issue with welcome.aspx? Just max post size is remaiing?

Comment: First let's try to make welcome.aspx page working. Why do you want to remove post? Because that page is within post folder

Comment: Its i need for SEO url links , thats why i change

Comment: So you need to use url rewriting module for asp.net

Comment: how to write url writing?

Comment: Check this, http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module